# Javascript menu blocking in different browsers

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, cross-browser

I have created a menu using javascript like this..

**Code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       //slides the element with class "menu_body" when paragraph 
       //with class "menu_head" is clicked
       $("#firstpane p.menu_head").click(function () {
              $(this).css({ backgroundImage: "url('../images/down.png')"        
       }).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
       $(this).siblings().css({ backgroundImage: "url('../images/left.png')" });
   });         
</script>
```

It is working fine. But in different browsers sometimes the menu is locking. It varies on different computers. For example: on one system the problem is with chrome and on another it's with Mozilla. Tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Put your `css classes` and `html` also. It will be better if you create a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: can we have the whole code in jsfiddle...

Comment: it is here http://jsfiddle.net/dHhpM/

Comment: You can't use ASP tags in a Fiddle, OP. Copy and paste the result of `view source` on the problematic page.